# How to make a proper search method in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, fetch-api

I'm new in Redux and need help with my search.

I need to fetch search results using some API. This API gives me following endpoints:

```
POST /search/
GET /search/:id/results
```

So I need to do:

1. Make a post request with my search data
2. Then when I get its response, I take a specific search id
3. Make a get request with this id to get my results.

I'm trying to fetch results the following way:

```
const FETCH_RESULTS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_RESULTS_SUCCESS';

const initialState = {
  results: []
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_RESULTS_SUCCESS:
        return Object.assign([], state, { results: action.results });

    default:
        return state;
  }
}

export const fetchResults = id => dispatch => {
  return
    fetch(`/search/${id}/results`, {
      method: 'get',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(results => {
      dispatch({
       type: FETCH_RESULTS_SUCCESS,
       results
      })
    })

export const createSearch = data => dispatch => {
  return fetch('/search/', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => data.id)
  .then(id => dispatch(fetchResults(id)))
}
```

The problem is that it gives me empty results, but if I put some real search id (assume we have previous searches in database) like this `dispatch(fetchResults(15)` it will give me results.

Why passing id this way doesn't work?

```
.then(data => data.id)
.then(id => dispatch(fetchResults(id)))
```

Is my approach ok or maybe you would advise me to implement a search with such API some other way?

P.S. Code may have some typos.

Comment: Are you using redux-thunk?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: You can make both calls in a single action. Just chain the promises.

Comment: @OriDrori Thanks, I've just tried it, but no luck. I think the problem is how I pass id to next fetch.  How can I pass id from post request response to next get request?

Comment: It's not the solution to your problem. You just don't need to actions for this. Replace `dispatch(fetchResults(id))` with `console.log(id)`. What do you see?

Comment: @OriDrori I get a correct search id.

Comment: @OriDrori And I want to pass this id to dispatch my fetchResults. It works like this `dispatch(fetchResults(15))`, bot not `dispatch(fetchResults(id))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157398/discussion-between-ori-drori-and-dair).